# Get the real path of a shared library in linux

Tags: python, linux, shared-libraries

How can I get the real path of a shared library in linux if I only know the library name and without its version number?

e.g., libc/libcudart/libcudnn/librt/libcurl/...

They may be in standard directories (e.g. those specified in ldconfig cache) or other directories (e.g. those specified in LD_LIBRARY_PATH)

You can use linux tools or python or your own code.

Comment: `ldconfig -v` .

Comment: @Roadowl Some libs are not in ldconfig's cache.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/54736/how-to-check-if-a-library-is-installed

Comment: @KamilCuk I read all of the answers in your link, but none of them can solve my problem (most of them don't respect LD_LIBRARY_PATH, e.g. using ldconfig or gcc -lxxx)

Comment: If so, then I'll believe write an utility yourself. I suggest write a patch to `ldd`, along `ldd --find xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

The following bash scripts with GNU utilities refreshes ld cache and handles `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by itself:

```
$ { printf "%s" "$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" |
     xargs -r -i{} -d':' find {} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f;
     tmp=$(mktemp) ; trap 'rm "$tmp"' EXIT
     ldconfig -C "$tmp"
     ldconfig -C "$tmp" -v 2>&1 |
     awk '
          /^[^\t]/{gsub(/:.*/,""); sec=$0; print; next; }
          /\t*[^ ]* -> /{ a[sec "/" $1]; a[sec "/" $3]; }
          END{ for (i in a) print i }';
   } | grep 'libc.so'
/usr/lib/libc.so.6
/usr/lib32/libc.so.6
```

Comment: I cannot update ld cache because I don't have root permission on most of the machines. I'm investigating dlinfo() function...

Comment: `ldconfig -C /tmp/cache ; ldconfig -C /tmp/cache -v` ....

Answer (score 0):

If you know any executable which is using the library then you can use `ldd (/usr/bin/ldd)` like so:

```
user@Inspiron:~/code/general$ ldd /usr/bin/python
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffe89326000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4b0b986000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4b0b963000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4b0b95d000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f4b0b958000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f4b0b809000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f4b0b7db000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f4b0b7bd000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4b0bb8e000)
```